# Is there a way to perform a double tap using Appium on Android?

Tags: android, appium

I've tried every combination of TouchActions and chaining I can think of to perform a double tap on Android using the Appium integration test framework. I'm only able to record a single tap. Here's the (Java) code I would expect to work:

```
new TouchAction(driver).tap(x, y).tap(0, 0).perform();
```

Does anyone have a working Android code sample to share?

For reference, in iOS, the following (Python) code does seem to produce a double tap:

```
wd = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
...
wd.tap([(215, 315)])
wd.tap([(215, 315)])
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: did you find the way to perform double tap?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
action = TouchAction(self.driver)
action.tap(element=None, x=100, y=600, count=2).perform()
```

or with element and without x, y coordinates

(You have to import: "from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction")

Answer (score 0):

Double tap in Appium java by using x,y coordinate:

```
new TouchAction(driver).press(PointOption.point(328, 185)).release().perform().press(PointOption.point(338, 185)).release().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this appium geastures [Automating Mobile Gestures With UiAutomator2](https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/android-mobile-gestures/)

MobileElement button = driver.findElement(By.id("Button"));

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("mobile: doubleClickGesture", ImmutableMap.of("elementId",((MobileElement)button).getId()));

Answer (score 0):

TouchAction action = new TouchAction(Driver);

action.Tap(x, y).Wait(100).Tap(x, y).Perform();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).